# What is the use of 16 Bytes chaddr in DHCP packet header?

Tags: dhcp, mac-address

Why DHCP has 16 Bytes reserved for chaddr in the BOOTP header ?

As per my knowledge DHCP is IPoE, so 48 Bits/ 6 BYtes should be enough ?

Is the answer is same, means "for future purpose" ? Because i don't see now it's helpful in case of InfiniBand.

Anywhere it's documented with valid reason ?

Comment: Simple. Ethernet is not the only layer-2 in the universe.

Comment: i am not so good in depth of layer 2 thing but as per my understanding DHCP is designed as IPoE correct ? if so then ethernet takes the help of MAC.. if other protocols like ATM will be used they how ? is it documented in rfc ?

Comment: Incorrect. DHCP is a means of providing an IP address - period. It is not, and never has been, tied to any particular layer-2.

Comment: I need more proof, because still now i am not seeing any DHCP with other hardware type ? As i have seen some codes they are only caring about MAC. Adding a comment line from DHCP ISC...  * When we lookup a lease by chaddr, we know the MAC address matches the lease record*

Here they takes the CHADDR as MAC only

Comment: Do not make assumptions based on one implementation. **THE STANDARD** does not specify a layer-2; chaddr is 16bytes to support things that *are not ethernet*. (bluetooth, zigbee, fiber channel, token ring, FDDI, and so on.)

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

RFC2131 p. 7:

```
   From the client's point of view, DHCP is an extension of the BOOTP
   mechanism.  This behavior allows existing BOOTP clients to
   interoperate with DHCP servers without requiring any change to the
   clients' initialization software. 

   FIELD      OCTETS       DESCRIPTION
   -----      ------       -----------
   chaddr       16  Client hardware address.
```

https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2131.txt

Comment: so it's related to BOOTP ? Because as per the rfc 1542

   The bit ordering used for link-level hardware addresses in the
   'chaddr' field SHOULD be the same as the ordering used for the ARP
   protocol [4] on the client's link-level network (assuming ARP is
   defined for that network).

Why BOOTP is making some standardisation because of ARP ? As per my knowledge first is getting an IP then updating the ARP cache.. is it because of reason ARP can use any types of hardware ?